# How can i add click handler to x-label element of gwt-visualisation chart

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, svg, gchart

I am using gwt-visualisation chart

But is there any way to add click handler to x-label

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the gwt-visualisation library but try adding the label to a `FocusPanel` to which you can add a click handler.